# How do I solve Unknown database error in Yii2?

Tags: php, database, yii2

My Friend Suggested me to use Yii2 Framework And sent me all the  files of a project he has worked upon, including the .sql file which he exported from phpmyadmin. I am trying to edit the same project (with his permission). After importing the .sql file i changed the database name username and password in \config\db.php and got this error

Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'mydb'

Here is my db.php :

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',


];
```

Then I Downloaded basic Yii2 application from official Yii Site (which works working fine), then i replaced \controllers\SiteController.php from the directory of the project that my friend sent me with the one i downloaded. To my Surprise the error was gone but it still looked like same as the one i downloaded (The one my friend sent was a educational school website, so it is supposed to look the same).

Here is SiteController.php of the one that my friend sent me

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\ContactForm;
use app\modules\admin\models\AdmissionEnquiryForm;
use app\models\Article;
use app\models\ArticleSearch;
use app\modules\admin\models\SidebarModule;
use app\modules\admin\models\SidebarModuleSearch;
use app\modules\admin\models\Gallery;
use app\modules\admin\models\Activities;
use app\modules\admin\models\Newsletter;
use app\modules\admin\models\VisitorCounter;



class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout', 'change-password'],
                //'except' =>['login'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout', 'change-password'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return string
     */

/*
    public function actionIndex()
    {
    $model  = Article::find()->where(['id' => 1])->one(); 
    return  $this->render('index').
    $this->renderPartial('//article/overview', [
            'model' => $this->findModel(1),
        ]);

    }


     public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->layout='articles';
        return $this->render('index', [
            'model' => $this->findModel(1),
        ]);
    }
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->layout='home';
        $sidebar=new SidebarModule;
        $newsletter= new Newsletter;
        /*$counter=new VisitorCounter;

        $counter->counter=+1;
        $counter->save();
        $visits=VisitorCounter::find()->max('id');
        $visits->counter=+1;
        $visits->save();
        //var_dump($visits);
        */
        $visits=VisitorCounter::find()->where(['id'=>1])->One();
        $visits->counter=$visits->counter+1;
        $visits->save();

        $this->view->params['newsletter'] = $newsletter;
       // var_dump($_POST);
        if ($newsletter->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $newsletter->save())  {
        //Yii::$app->user->setFlash('success', "you are successfully subscribed to our Newsletter");
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "you are successfully subscribed to our Newsletter");
       // $newsletter->email=($_POST['email']);

        }
        return $this->render('index',['sidebar'=>$sidebar]);

    }



    /**
     * Login action.
     *
     * @return Response|string
     */
    /*
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        }

        $model->password = '';
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
*/
    public function actionLogin() {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
        $this->layout = '@app/themes/backend/login';
        $model = new LoginForm(['scenario' => 'login']);
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load($_POST)) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->user->getReturnUrl());
        }
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Logout action.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    /**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return Response|string
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {

        $model = new ContactForm();
        $model->subject = "Enquiry from website";

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {


            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');
            return $this->refresh();


                }
        //return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
                return $this->render('contact', ['model' => $model]);

        }

          public function actionAdmissionEnquiryForm()
    {

        $model = new AdmissionEnquiryForm();
        $model->subject = "Enquiry for admission";

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->admission(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {


            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('AdmissionEnquiryFormSubmitted');
            return $this->refresh();


                }
        //return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
                return $this->render('AdmissionEnquiryForm', ['model' => $model]);

        }

    public function actionChangePassword() {
        $this->layout = '@app/themes/backend/main';
        $userId = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $model = User::find()->where(['id' => $userId])->one();
        $model->scenario = 'changeP';
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $oldpassword = $model->oldpassword;
            $password = $model->password;
            $hash = $model->password_hash;
            $result = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($oldpassword, $hash);
            $NewPassword = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);
            if ($result) {
                $model->password_hash = $NewPassword;
                $confirm = $model->save();
                if ($confirm) {
                    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('passwordChanged');
                    $link = Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['site/signin']);

                    return $this->refresh();
                }
            } else {
                $model->addError('oldpassword', 'Incorrect old password.');
            }
        }
        return $this->render('change-password',
            ['model' => $model]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }

     protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Article::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
    }

    public function actionGallery($id=null) {

                $activities = Activities::find()->where(['status' => 1])->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC])->all();
                $model = Activities::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();


               // var_dump($model1);
                $latestActivity = Activities::find()->max('id');

                if($id==null){

                    $gallery = Gallery::find()->where(['status' => 'active','activity_name'=>$latestActivity])->all(); 
                }else{
                    $gallery = Gallery::find()->where(['status' => 'active','activity_name'=>$id])->all();                    
                }

                return $this->render('gallery', ['gallery' => $gallery,'activities'=>$activities,'model'=>$model]);

    }

}
```

And here is the SiteController.php of the one i downloaded

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * Login action.
     *
     * @return Response|string
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        }

        $model->password = '';
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Logout action.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    /**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return Response|string
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

            return $this->refresh();
        }
        return $this->render('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }
}
```

Note : The Files he sent me are of Sailor theme of Yii2.

How do solve the database not found error? Also please help me understand how replacing config.php from basic yii2 application (which I downloaded)  with the one which is already there isn't showing error. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want help with, could you elaborate?

Comment: How do solve the database not found error?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the error is because in db.php have you specified the database name `mydb`, but that database doesn't exist (or, perhaps you don't have permission on it, although that's unlikely since you're using the root user).

Are you certain the database exists on your local database instance? Does your user (root) have the correct permissions to see and access the database?

Most likely this is the problem, either the database is called something else or doesn't exist at all, so you should either create the database on your local system or change the name db.php is looking for.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, the database exists and i can access it after i login into root. The Same database works  after replacing config.php from basic yii2 application (which I downloaded) with the one already inn there in the directory (which my friend sent).